# Is an iterative process that returns a list with size that increases by iteration any different from an one that returns a scalar?

Tags: functional-programming, iteration, scheme, tail-recursion, sicp

This actually comes from me initially misreading the text of [Exercise 1.12](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%25_thm_1.12).

The request is indeed to

> Write a procedure that computes elements of Pascal's triangle by means of a recursive process.

I crucially mistook *recursive* for *iterative*, and spent quite a bit trying to understand where in the world I could come up with a number of numbers that could describe the state of the computation at any given stage, but I didn't come up with anything. Quite the opposite, I think that you can't just represent the state of the computation of the triangle with a constant number of scalars.

So I eventually re-read the exercise statement, realized my mistake and completed the exercise the intended way.

But still, the fact that an iterative process for that solution is not required in following exercises either, made me think that maybe such a solution either doesn't exist, or it has some properties that make it fundamentally different from other recursive procedures implemented as iterative processes.

Anyway, I was curious, so thought: what if the state is not a number but a list? In that case, pretty naturally the state of the computation is the previous row of the triangle; i.e., all one needs to compute each and all of the elements of the *n*-th row of the triangle is the *n-1*-th row.

So I came up with this procedure

```lisp
(define (pascal i j)
  (define (update t)
    (concat (cons 1 (zipWith+ (cdr t) t)) '(1)))
  (define (pascal-impl i t)
    (if (= i 0)
        t
        (pascal-impl (- i 1) (update t))))
  (element (pascal-impl i '(1)) j))
```

where `pascal-impl` carries on the state `t` of the computation of the trianlge (a row) and the count `i`. Then the main function `pascal` picks the appropriate entry from the required row.

Now, leaving aside the understandable inefficiency due to the usage of a bare list, I was wondering

- if the procedure above is to be classified as iterative,
- and whether/how having the state of the iteration be an entity of size increasing with the depth of the iteration influences the properties of an iterative process. Or, instead, the state increasing in size and the iterative nature of the process are "orthogonal" properties?

---

I'm assuming these utilities or, again, a better performing version of them, are available:

```lisp
(define (zipWith+ a b)
  (if (null? a)
      '()
      (cons (+ (car a) (car b)) 
            (zipWith+ (cdr a) (cdr b)))))

(define (concat a b)
  (if (null? a)
      b
      (cons (car a) 
            (concat (cdr a) b))))

(define (element xs i)
  (if (= i 0)
      (car xs)
      (element (cdr xs) (- i 1))))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nice properties"?

Comment: @Bergi, I've tried to clarify (beside correcting the name of the triangle :D).

Comment: I don't think there's anything fundamental about iterative processes that says the loop variable must be a scalar. Your example, where you loop/recurse over the *size* of a list, is actually on the more trivial side, there are also loops where the condition depends on the list *contents*.

Comment: @Bergi here state is the list (the last calculated row), not its size. this includes its contents as well.

Comment: BTW *iteration* has no "depth", only "length" or "duration" maybe.

Comment: @WillNess Sure a list is stored in the loop variable, but the loop invariant that we look at for reasoning about termination is just that its size grows - the element values are irrelevant for that

Comment: @Bergi I'd disagree. a loop invariant is something we preserve while looping, and here it is the fact that the list is the last produced row in the Pascal triangle. we are able to use it in the certain way based on the assumption that it is, not just that its size is right.

Comment: of course you might argue that its contents are determined by its size, and you'd be right, but that would imply a totally different algorithm. :) @Bergi

Answer (score 1):

"Iterative" simply means not recursive. Thus, your `pascal-impl`, being tail-recursive, actually describes a loop, so is indeed iterative.

The size of the state is indeed an orthogonal issue. In your function it is indeed growing as *~ 2n* for the *n*th step.

As an aside, `zipWith+` can be coded as a right fold over the list's tails (i.e. its iterated `cdr`s), eliminating the need for the `concat`:

```
(define (next-row a)
  (define (go a)
    (cond 
       ((null? a)
          '())
       ((null? (cdr a))
          (list 1))
       (else
          (cons (+ (car a) (cadr a))
                (go (cdr a))))))
  (cons 1 (go a)))
```

Another line of optimization is, since you only produce one element in the end, let its index guide your iteration and produce only as much of the triangle as needed, which will be of a  skewed  rhombic shape.

Comment: A-ah, so you're saying that tail-recursive is a misnomer, because a tail-recursive function is not recursive! :P

Comment: "tail-recursive" relates to a syntactical property. in Scheme it's just how the loops are written down.

Comment: there's not much difference between a recursive call and re-entering a loop body. both have local variables, and arguments/loop vars play the same role.